# How to fill the pixel gap in Image

Tags: image, opencv, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I am doing shadow generation for cars, but since CNN give fixed-sized output, and it also returns a pixelated output because I resized it to lower size. So, I am trying to get back the image to its original size by applying shadow from the resized image and applying it to the original image.

Algorithm;

1. Original Image size (1024, 768, 4) [Without shadow].
2. Resize original image [Without shadow] to (768, 512, 4) and generate the shadow using GANs model which will return image [With shadow] of size (768, 512, 4).
3. Now because the about image is pixelated (because of the resize). I am trying to remove the shadow of (768, 512, 4) size image and apply it to the Original image of size (1024, 768, 4).
4. But, when I am resizing the shadow and then applying it to the original image it outputs is like below.

basically, I am trying to remove the shadow border between car and shadow.

[image]

[Original Input image (1024, 768, 4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpbvi.jpg)

[Resized Input image (768, 512, 4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNYs7.png)

[Resized Output image (768, 512, 4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZUpy.png)

Comment: can you also post the separate images of the car and the shadow so that we can try different methods for mixing them together?

Comment: @ian-chu Can you check now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vishal T, try to merge if RGBA images are used

alphaComposited = Image.alpha_composite(car, shadow)

https://pythontic.com/image-processing/pillow/alpha-composite

if RGB images, try

Image.composite

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-composite-method/

let me know how it works for you. I faced similar issue with similar work. Good luck :)

Comment: It did not work, I had to do a lot of post-processing to fill those gaps. ended up doing masking and filling.

Comment: @VishalT can you post the solution here? it will be helpful for others.